# Executing a background process in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, background-process

I'm rewriting [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process#45966) for Windows and so far I've come up with this:

```
 // Escape character for Windows is: ^ 
 $shellCmd = 'start /B cmd /c ' . escapeshellcmd($cmd) . ' ^>"'.$outputfile. '"'; 
 // note that exec was like 40 times slower than popen & pclose 
 pclose(popen($shellCmd, "r"));
```

There's `tasklist` command on Windows but I don't know how to find out the PID of my process. To be punctual I'm looking for PID of the process that is opened via popen.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

**Note:** I'm not sure what this code does with error output but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm looking for PID of the process that is opened via popen.

Comment: You should add that as the first sentence of your question :)

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php
http://www.php.net/proc_get_status

read discussion under these functions and you can get more control over background processes and retrieve their PIDs

example like this:

```
$pcs = popen($shellCmd,"r");
$info = proc_get_status($pcs);
$pid = $info['pid'];
proc_close($pcs);
```

Comment: I've already read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#90584 but it is not kind of portable solution.

Comment: You should use `proc_open` and `proc_close`. This snippet returns warning: `supplied resource is not a valid stream resource`. I'll add working code when I finish :)

Comment: sorry, my fault, haven't tested the code, just repaired snippet :)

Comment: A problem that bugs me is that I would like to get PID of $cmd but $pid now contains PID of `start` command (as expected) and I'm really at loss how to find out the subprocess PID.